# CODEIGNITER3 framework shows that page does not exist while editing the post

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written some code in CodeIgniter3 framework for editing and updating the post. But when I click submit button it redirects to 404 page and shows that there is no such page like here [image] I tried to make $data in controller, then moved it to model it did not work, and now I do not know where is the problem. Here is my view:

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'rex-forms', 'name' => 'editcourse', 'id' => 'editcourse', 'data-parsley-validate' => ''); ?>
      <?php echo form_open_multipart('courses/update', $attributes); ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="courses_slug" value="<?= $courses['courses_slug'];?>">

    <!--  General -->

    HERE IS SOME CODE

</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function edit($courses_slug) {

        //check login
         if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('');
         }

        $data['courses'] = $this->popular_courses_model->get_popular_courses($courses_slug);

        //check user

        if($this->session->userdata('id') != $data['courses']['instructor_id']){
            redirect('');
        }

        $data['categories'] = $this->courses_model->get_all_categories_for_courses();
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Course';

        if (empty($data['courses'])) {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('courses/editcourse', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function update() {
        //check login
         if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('');
         }

        $this->courses_model->update_post();

        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('blog');
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
public function update_post() {
        //insert image
            $config['upload_path']   = './assets/img/single_courses/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']      = 4096;
            $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);


            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){

                $post_image =  '';
            } else {
                $datar = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            }  

            //insert the user registration details into database
            $slugtitle = mb_strtolower($this->input->post('name'), 'UTF-8');
            $slug = url_title($slugtitle);

            $data = array(
                'title' => strip_tags($this->input->post('name')),
                'duration' => $this->input->post('duration'),
                'certification' => $this->input->post('certification'),
                'price' => strip_tags($this->input->post('price')),
                'begining' => $this->input->post('begining'),
                'courses_description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'purpose' => $this->input->post('purpose'),
                'courses_slug' => $slug,
                'instructor_id' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
                'category_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
                'img' => $post_image
            );

        $this->db->where('courses_slug', $this->input->post('courses_slug'));
        return $this->db->update('courses', $data);
    }
```

Comment: if you don't use routing, you are calling a controller `courses`, which then calls an unknown page in funvtion update

Comment: @Vickel, thanks! I forgot to add a route :D But I have one question. I am new in programming. What are these routes do? Why it did not work before adding the route?

Comment: CI routing is very well documented here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html Without routing you will follow the CI url approach like here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html, which means (as by your screenshot) you call the function `update` from within your controller `courses`. Follow the tutorials at CI homepage, you'll learn a lot!

Comment: Try with index.php in url `http://localhost/projectname/index.php/courses/update` it may be that you need a new htacces or you might have to set some routes up https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: please post your reoutes.php file, the problem might be there

Answer (score 0):

You are using a model popular_courses_model but have you loaded the model in autoload as you have not loaded it in your controller.

```
$this->load->model('popular_courses_model');
```

Your model is missing certain constructs unless you have just posted the function here out of your model. Assuming you have not, your model needs to look something like this:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Popular_courses_model extends CI_Model
{     
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Whatever code you want in your constructor
    }

    public function update_post()
    {
        // your code here
    }    
}
```

And your model would be Popular_courses_model.php with capitalisation and in your 'models' folder.

Hope that helps,

Paul

Comment: I have all these in my model https://yadi.sk/i/eISeHes13MwYsr . But i do not know how to solve the problem